# Linebreak in Package algorithm2e

Tags: line-breaking, algorithm2e

I'm using the **algorithm2e** package for pseudocode. I got some very long lines that needed to be wrapped. Is there a way to indent the  following (breaked) lines and/or put a mark at the first line to signalize that there happened a linebreak (similar to [solution for listings package](http://www.bollchen.de/blog/2011/04/good-looking-line-breaks-with-the-listings-package/))

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965702/latex-line-breaking-of-long-lines-how-to-mark-these) for the listings package, that was answered before, but I'm looking explicitly for an *algorithm2e* solution.

Comment: See also the [related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153646/1347) if you want to skip line numbers for manually wrapped lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following minimal example defines

- `\nosemic`: remove printing of the end-of-line (EOL) character (typically `;`);
- `\dosemic`: reinstate printing of the EOL character;
- `\pushline`: indents line by `1em` (the typical indent); provided by `algorithm2e` as `\Indp`;
- `\popline`: remove indent of `\pushline` (undent?); provided by `algorithm2e` as `\Indm`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\relax}}% Drop semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\dosemic}{\renewcommand{\@endalgocfline}{\algocf@endline}}% Reinstate semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\pushline}{\Indp}% Indent
\newcommand{\popline}{\Indm\dosemic}% Undent
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
    initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      \nosemic this is a very long statement that has to be\;
        \pushline\dosemic wrapped over two lines\;
      \popline current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}​
```

Since I am unfamiliar with your [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) setup, I'm not sure how you would like to combine the four commands. As such, I've kept them separate for maximum (yet manual) usage.

Answer (score 5):

In fact there is a simpler solution: use classical `\hangafter` and `\hangindent`. This works fine with `algorithm2e`.

Notes:

1. `\skiptext` is the length of text indent in algorithm for a new block; so I choose 1/2 of this indent;
2. no need to redefine internal macro as `\algocf@endline` as almost all can be redefined in `algorithm2e`. Use `\SetEndCharOfAlgoLine` to redefine end of line

See below for an example of use of `\hangafter` and `\hangindent`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
%
\newcommand{\nosemic}{\SetEndCharOfAlgoLine{\relax}}% Drop semi-colon ;
\newcommand{\dosemic}{\SetEndCharOfAlgoLine{\string;}}% Reinstate
\newcommand{\pushline}{\Indp}% Indent
\newcommand{\popline}{\Indm\dosemic}% Undent
%
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
    initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      \nosemic this is a very long statement that has to be\;
        \pushline\dosemic wrapped over two lines\;
      \popline current section becomes this one\;
      \hangindent=.5\skiptext\hangafter=1
      this is a very long statement that should be indented automatically on the next
      lines if this statement is longer than one line\;
      Following lines should be indented normally\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}​
```

Answer (score 0):

`\Indp` and `\Indm` can be used in the package `algorithm2e` for indent and removing indent. I have tested it.