# Vertical lines for blocks of pseudocode

Tags: algorithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linebreak in Package algorithm2e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37181/linebreak-in-package-algorithm2e)

Is it somehow possible to generate vertical alines that connect the start and end of a block in `algpseudocode` (as provided by the `algorithmicx` package) or any other algorithm environment? E.g. something like this:

```
for ... do
|    for ... do
|    |    if ... then
|    |        ...
|    |    end if
|    end for
end for
```

Thin and possibly grey lines where the `|` are would be appreciated. It would make rather long and deeply nested code more readable. (I know splitting the code into several functions could help sometimes, but still this would be nice to have.)

I don't know how to deal with line breaks in pseudocode that would overlap with these lines. I guess it would be best if they would interrupt the lines, such as this:

```
for ... do
|    for ... do
|    |    a very long line (e.g. introduced by a comment) that
continues here and interrupts the lines on the left
|    end for
end for
```

But this is a minor detail, of course.

Comment: Almost similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37181/linebreak-in-package-algorithm2e

Comment: This question is very similar to [Is it possible to have connecting loop lines (like `algorithm2e`) in `algorithmic`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52473/5764). Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm2e package can do this. However, it requires (as far as I can tell) that you use their floating environment.

See http://ctan.unixbrain.com/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.pdf for details and examples.