# Is it possible to have connecting loop lines (like algorithm2e) in algorithmic?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I am using the `algorithmic` package to typeset an algorithm. I would like to have connecting lines between the beginning and end of a loop or conditional like in the `algorithm2e` package. Is there an easy way to accomplish this, or am I better off switching to `algorithm2e`?

Comment: I recommend switching.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using [`algorithmicx`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/) - more advanced yet similar to and compatible with [`algorithmic`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms). It involves expanding and contracting a token list `\thelines` that keeps track of the nested level. At every new level, an additional `\theline` is added to `\thelines`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\makeatletter
% This is the vertical rule that is inserted
\def\therule{\makebox[\algorithmicindent][l]{\hspace*{.5em}\vrule height .75\baselineskip depth .25\baselineskip}}%

\newtoks\therules% Contains rules
\therules={}% Start with empty token list
\def\appendto#1#2{\expandafter#1\expandafter{\the#1#2}}% Append to token list
\def\gobblefirst#1{% Remove (first) from token list
  #1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\@gobble\the#1}}%
\def\LState{\State\unskip\the\therules}% New line-state
\def\pushindent{\appendto\therules\therule}%
\def\popindent{\gobblefirst\therules}%
\def\printindent{\unskip\the\therules}%
\def\printandpush{\printindent\pushindent}%
\def\popandprint{\popindent\printindent}%

%      ***      DECLARED LOOPS      ***
% (from algpseudocode.sty)
\algdef{SE}[WHILE]{While}{EndWhile}[1]
  {\printandpush\algorithmicwhile\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}
  {\popandprint\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicwhile}%
\algdef{SE}[FOR]{For}{EndFor}[1]
  {\printandpush\algorithmicfor\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}
  {\popandprint\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}%
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForAll}[1]
  {\printindent\algorithmicforall\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}%
\algdef{SE}[LOOP]{Loop}{EndLoop}
  {\printandpush\algorithmicloop}
  {\popandprint\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicloop}%
\algdef{SE}[REPEAT]{Repeat}{Until}
  {\printandpush\algorithmicrepeat}[1]
  {\popandprint\algorithmicuntil\ #1}%
\algdef{SE}[IF]{If}{EndIf}[1]
  {\printandpush\algorithmicif\ #1\ \algorithmicthen}
  {\popandprint\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}%
\algdef{C}[IF]{IF}{ElsIf}[1]
  {\popandprint\pushindent\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif\ #1\ \algorithmicthen}%
\algdef{Ce}[ELSE]{IF}{Else}{EndIf}
  {\popandprint\pushindent\algorithmicelse}%
\algdef{SE}[PROCEDURE]{Procedure}{EndProcedure}[2]
   {\printandpush\algorithmicprocedure\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
   {\popandprint\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicprocedure}%
\algdef{SE}[FUNCTION]{Function}{EndFunction}[2]
   {\printandpush\algorithmicfunction\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
   {\popandprint\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d.\ of a and b}
      \LState $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
        \LState $a\gets b$
        \LState $b\gets r$
        \LState $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \LState \Return $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Every single definition is redefined to now manage the indentation:

- At the start of every block, you insert `\printindent` and append `\pushindent`. This removes the regular algorithmic indent `\algorithmicindent` and prints the vertical rule. At the end it adds another indent so that subsequent statements are properly indented; and
- At the end of every block, you insert `\popindent\printindent`. This removes the regular algorithmic indent `\algorithmicindent`, then swallows one indent, and prints the remaining indents.

I've added some additional macros like `\printandpush` and `\popandprint` to combine the above `\printindent`, `\pushindent` and `\popindent` modifications.

Instead of using the traditional `\State` for procedural statements, use `\LState`. It performs a similar task to what is mentioned above.

This solution should work well for the standard environments defined about. However, other more complicated environments defined using `\algdef` may require more fiddling to obtain correct indentation.

Regarding the vertical rule. It is set at `.5em` from the left-most margin of the block, is `.4pt` wide and is defined by `\therule`:

```
\def\therule{%
  \makebox[\algorithmicindent][l]{%
    \hspace*{.5em}\vrule height .75\baselineskip depth .25\baselineskip}}%
```

Token list appending is described in [How does one append material to a token list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38067/5764), while token removal is discussed in [How does one remove material from a token list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52653/5764)

Comment: Nice solution!!

Comment: Hello, please i'd like to add lines between while and endwhile like you, this is my example  \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
 \caption{My algo}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \WHILE{condition}
 \STATE instruction 1
 \STATE instruction 2
 \ENDWHILE
 \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
 \end{document}

Comment: should i add \usepackage{algpseudocode} ...... with \usepackage{algorithm} \usepackage{algorithmic}  or should i delete \usepackage{algorithmic} ?

Comment: @researcher: The code in my answer was written for `algpseudocode` from [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). So you need `\usepackage{algorithm}\usepackage{algpseudocode}` and then change all the `\STATE` to `\State`, `\WHILE` to `\While`, `\ENDWHILE` to `\EndWhile`. I'll see what needs to be done when you want to use `algcompatible`, which seems to be the code you're using. Once I have that covered, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: thank you for answer it works your solution, i ask please how can change while to "tant que "(in frensh), i try with i \renewcommand{\algorithmicwhile}{\textbf{Tant que}} i set it before your code but it didn't work!

Comment: @researcher: If you use my example code as-is, you just have to add `\renewcommand{\algorithmicwhile}{\textbf{Tant que}}` in the preamble after `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` for it to work. I also assume you're *not* using `\usepackage{algcompatible}`.

Comment: \renewcommand{\algorithmicwhile}{\textbf{Tant que}} works but
\renewcommand{\algorithmicendwhile}{\textbf{Fin Tant que}} didn't work!!

Comment: @researcher: That's because there's no `\algorithmicendwhile` command. In fact, the end of a `\While` construct is made up of `\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicwhile`. So, you could either just do `\renewcommand{\algorithmicend}{\textbf{Fin}}`, or redefine the *entire* `\While` construct: `\algdef{SE}[WHILE]{While}{EndWhile}[1]
  {\printandpush\textbf{Tant que}\ #1\ \textbf{faire}}
  {\popandprint\textbf{Fin Tant que}}` I used [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com).

Comment: yes it works now, i'm sorry if i disturb you i have just another question: in my algoritm i'd like to add Début at the begining of the algoithm and FIN at the end and join them with a line, is that possible?

Comment: @researcher: Add `\algdef{SE}[ALGOBEGEND]{AlgBegin}{AlgEnd}{\printandpush\textbf{D\'ebut}}{\popandprint\textbf{Fin}}` and then you can use `\AlgBegin` and `\AlgEnd` just like you would `\Procedure` and `\EndProcedure`.

Comment: i test your solution, it works but the first instructios and 'Début' are on the same line ! and I have a  lengthy instruction it intersects the line that connects 'Début' to 'Fin'!! Thank you

Comment: It does not seem to work properly with `\ForAll`. Would it be correct to use

`\algdef{SE}[FOR]{ForAll}{EndFor}[1]
  {\printandpush\algorithmicforall\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}
  {\popandprint\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}%`

instead of

`\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForAll}[1]
  {\printindent\algorithmicforall\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}%`

?

Comment: nice solution! what if we want to use the noend option?

Comment: @vefthym: Why don't you just switch to [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) then?

Comment: @Werner I have already written a big algorithm and I was hoping there would be an easier solution than this, but I guess it is my last resort. Thanks again for the nice answer though (after a few years :).

Comment: thanks for nice solution. One has to use `LState` instead of `State`, other than that, your solution seems to work very well so far.