# The option vlined with algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Please i ask if it's possible to add the option:

```
[vlined]
```

withe the package

```
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}
```

This is my example:

```
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
 \caption{My algo}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \WHILE{condition}
 \STATE instruction 1
 \STATE instruction 2
 \ENDWHILE
 \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

i'd like to join while to \ENDWHILE with a line, is that possible ?

Comment: Hi researcher! In its current form, the question is much too terse. Please add more detail about what you're trying to achieve, what you've attempted so far, and in what way it didn't work. Also include a minimal working example, that is a complete, minimal example document (starting from `\documentclass`) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: See [this answer by Werner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52778/3954) to learn how to do it using `algorithmicx` (which is compatible with `algorithmic`, so you can use the much better `algorithmicx` instead of `algorithmic`).

Answer (score 2):

The `vlined` option appears to be defined in the `algorithm2e` package which is a different package for laying out algorithms. It also defines the mixed case commands such as `\Begin` and `\For` that you used in earlier questions. Perhaps you intended to use that package rather than `algorithmic` ?

Comment: i understand that it's not possible with \usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}  ?

Comment: I have never used either package but package option names correspond directly to code in each package you can't just use a name from one package as an option for another, obviously in an open source system it is always possible to add more code but you are presumably looking at some documentation or examples that told you about `vlined` but that documentation is not about the package you are using.