# Add line before Begin algorithm 'Début'

Tags: algorithms

This is a follow-up question to [Option in the algorithm with Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75519/option-in-the-algorithm-with-latex). This is my algorithm:

```
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
 \caption{My algo}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \Debut
 \LState instruction 1
 \LState instruction 2
  \Fin
 \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Please how can I add "Données" before "Début" ?

Comment: How did you define `\Debut` and `\Fin`?

Comment: it is werner'algo :\algnewcommand{\Debut}{\Statex \textbf{D\'ebut}\pushindent}
\algnewcommand{\Fin}{\Statex \textbf{Fin}\popindent}

Comment: Then define `\Donnees` in a similar way: `\algnewcommand{\Donnees}{\Statex\textbf{Donn\'ees}\pushindent}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
\algnewcommand{\Donnees}{\Statex \textbf{Donn\'ees}}
```

you can now obtain

[image]

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My algorithme}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Donnees: My data
    \Statex% Blank line
    \Debut
      \LState $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
        \LState $a\gets b$
        \LState $b\gets r$
        \LState $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \LState \textbf{Retour} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \Fin
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The use of `\Statex` inserts a blank line, depending on whether you need a separation between the algorithm and the input.

The above code snippet uses the same preamble as in [Option in the `algorithm` with LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75538/5764).

Comment: Please i have one more question: when i divide the algorithm after an IF and before an EndIF, i have an error , have you an idea please?