# algorithm2e Command \algorithm already defined

Tags: algorithms, incompatibility, algorithm2e

I want to draw vertical line by using `\SetAlgoLined`, but LaTeX told me `Undefined control sequence`.

Then I add `\usepackage{algorithm2e}` to the end of my preamble. Then it said `Command`\algorithm`already defined`.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{xthesis}  
\usepackage{xtocinc}  
\usepackage{mystyle}  
\usepackage{url}  
\usepackage{subfigure}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}  
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}  
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}  
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig}  
\usepackage{multicol}  
\usepackage{ifthen}  
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
```

I'm using Window 7 + TexWorks. I have another paper works perfect with `algorithm2e` and `\SetAlgoLined`:

```
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{url}  
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{multicol}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
```

Just had no idea why it happened? Please help.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to have connecting loop lines (like `algorithm2e`) in `algorithmic`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52473/5764)

Answer (score 43):

Since the `algorithm` and `algorithm2e` packages both define an `algorithm` environment, simply loading both with no extra precaution will cause a name clash like you experienced.

However, you can still use both packages (if you *really* need both), but you need to pass the option `algo2e` to `algorithm`:

```
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}
```

This option changes the name of the environment `algorithm` from the `algorithm2e` package into `algorithm2e` and so avoids the conflict with the package which already define an `algorithm` environment; the option also changes
the command name for the list of algorithms to `\listofalgorithmes`.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}  
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e} 

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}%>- from algorithm package
test
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm2e}%>- from algorithm2e package
test
\end{algorithm2e}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It resolved my question. But now the line number cannot be set

Answer (score 3):

The [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) (which provides the `algorithm` and `algorithmic` packages) is not compatible with [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e). The latter is self-contained, providing both the floating environment `algorithm` (also provided by `algorithms`' `algorithm` package) as well as programming constructs (like `If`, `Else`, `While`, etc).

In terms of your algorithm layout, you have to choose - either construct your algorithms using elements from the `algorithms` bundle, or `algorithm2e`.