# Pseudo code algorithm not showing in a frame

Tags: algorithm2e, pseudocode

I am using this code to show a pseudocode:

```
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
...
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwResult{Write here the result }
 initialization\;
 \While{While condition}{
  instructions\;
  \eIf{condition}{
   instructions1\;
   instructions2\;
   }{
   instructions3\;
  }
 }
 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
```

The result is this without any frame around:

[image]

If I include `\usepackage{algorithm}` I get a better result (altho non correct, see while):

[image]

But Latex (`sharelatex.com`) outputs some errors:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.sty, line 2334
LaTeX Error: Command \algorithm already defined.
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [algorithm2e Command \algorithm already defined](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131646/algorithm2e-command-algorithm-already-defined)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add `ruled` in the option while loading the package.

[image]

Code

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
 \begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwResult{Write here the result }
 initialization\;
 \While{While condition}{
  instructions\;
  \eIf{condition}{
   instructions1\;
   instructions2\;
   }{
   instructions3\;
  }
 }
 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```