# Table of contents of algorithm and algorithm2e together

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmic

The contents of the algorithms thinks that an algorithm that uses `algorithm` is one algorithm and an algorithm that uses `algorithm2e` is another algorithm, not the second of what was imported with the other package, but a different entity or something, which, in my opinion is not OK.

I would like this:

```
  1 algo 1..................... page of algo 1
1 algo 2..................... page of algo 2
```

to be changed to this:

```
1 algo 1..................... page of algo 1
2 algo 2..................... page of algo 2
```

Alignment and numbering were changed above.

Here is the minimal example, based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131646/algorithm2e-command-algorithm-already-defined) question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}  
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e} 
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{List of Algorithms}
\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}

\begin{document}
    \listofalgorithms
    \smallskip
    \begin{algorithm}%>- from algorithm package
        test
        \caption{algo 1}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithm2e}%>- from algorithm2e package
        test
        \caption{algo 2}
    \end{algorithm2e}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

---

*Chronicle*

I had my thesis ready. However, just last night we submitted a paper based on it. I must submit my thesis too and I would like to include some of the algorithms written to the paper into the thesis. For several reasons, I have come into a situation where someone will give a solution to my problem, or I will just leave the the thesis without the paper-algorithms, which of course lead to a heartbroken thesis. :)

The algorithms of the paper are written with `algorithm2e`, while the algorithms of the thesis are written with `algorithm` and `algorithmic`. I have to submit it first thing tomorrow morning, thus I have no time to re-write them (I am editing my thesis now in other sections), that's why I will either hear a solution from the community here, or will leave the algorithms of the paper outside of my thesis!

Comment: The purpose of the question is not clear. What is the problem here?

Comment: Sorry @CarlosViegas, edited!

Comment: Let me ask you, why do you need to use different algorithm packages? Why not only `algorithm` package?

Comment: Expected @CarlosViegas, see my edit. I did not write them for keeping the post short!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution is to use `\setcounter` inside each algorithm. Moreover, to get the algorithms aligned in the list of algorithms you need to redefine `\listof` and `\l@algocf` commands and set `\@dottedtocline` with the desired horizontal spacing. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}  
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e} 
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{List of Algorithms}
\addtocontents{loa}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}

% add this to align the list of algorithms
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\listof}[2]{%
    \@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
      \@namedef{l@#1}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{2.3em}}% line of the list (change from 1em to the desired value)
      \float@listhead{#2}%
      \begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{\z@}%
        \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}%
      \endgroup}}
  \renewcommand*\l@algocf{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{2.3em}}% line of the list (change from 1em to the desired value)
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \listofalgorithms
    \smallskip
    \begin{algorithm}%>- from algorithm package
      \setcounter{algorithm}{0}% set the counter for the 1st algorithm
        test
        \caption{algo 1}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithm2e}%>- from algorithm2e package
      \setcounter{algocf}{1}% set the counter for the 2nd algorithm
        test
        \caption{algo 2}
    \end{algorithm2e}

    \begin{algorithm}%>- from algorithm package
      \setcounter{algorithm}{2}% set the counter for the 3rd algorithm
        test
        \caption{algo 3}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithm2e}%>- from algorithm2e package
      \setcounter{algocf}{3}% set the counter for the 4th algorithm
        test
        \caption{algo 4}
    \end{algorithm2e}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good Carlos. However, I can not accept it, because the first number at every row of a content is not aligned to each next one. For example, in my screenshot, first's item 1 is not aligned well with the first's item 1. If you do not understand me, please let me know. You should see when you run your example that 1, 2, 3 and 4 are not aligned harmonically, but it's like the indentation differs per package.

Comment: I understand you, but you asked for one thing (wrong numbering at LOA), now you want another (text alignment).

Comment: My bad Carlos, but it was not intended, I thought it was obvious. Sorry, I will edit my question accordingly. However, I think that you are close to the solution, so an edit of yours might save the day after all! :)

Comment: It is not that obvious, since here you are reproducing your problem with a minimal code example. And this code differs from the final format of your thesis. So, if you don't ask, we can't guess this is a problem. Anyway, I'm thinking about the alignment problem... but for now I don't know a solution.

Comment: I see Carlos, I will do better next time! Do not care about my thesis, work on the minimal example and if you can achieve in fixing this, then I will try to import it in my thesis.

Comment: I edited my code and the problem of alignment is now solved. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks Carlos! Bueno :) Sorry again for not being as clear as one would wish. :)