Missing number, treated as zero in \endif algorithm
Good evening,
I got an error when using algorithm in latex:
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% Font tiếng Việt
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\DH}{T1}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xurl}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
% Tài liệu tham khảo
\usepackage[
    sorting=nty,
    backend=bibtex,
    defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} % Bookmark tiếng Việt
\addbibresource{References/references.bib}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\makeatletter
\def\blx@maxline{77}
\makeatother

% Chèn hình, các hình trong luận văn được để trong thư mục Images/
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }

% Chèn và định dạng mã giả
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
% Dãn dòng 1.5
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

% Thụt vào đầu dòng
\usepackage{indentfirst}

% Canh lề
\usepackage[
  top=30mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  left=30mm,
  right=20mm,
  includefoot]{geometry}
  
% Trang bìa
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\HRule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}

\begin{document}

% Sasu trang Title, các bạn chèn nhận xét gủa GVHD và GVPB. Nhận xét sẽ được giáo vụ phát sau buổi bảo vệ để các bạn đóng quyển.

\pagenumbering{roman} % Đánh số i, ii, iii, ...

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic} % Đánh số 1, 2, 3, ...

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title={Tiếng Anh}, resetnumbers=true] 


\algnewcommand\algorithmicforeach{\textbf{for each}}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForEach}[1]{\algorithmicforeach\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Form Cluster and Learning a Radius $\lambda$}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require $\mathcal{S} = \{m_i \in M^d  \mid  \mathcal{E}(m_i) = e \}, \lambda, \epsilon$
\State $C \gets \emptyset$
\State $r \gets 0$
\State Randomly sample $m_i$ from $\mathcal{S}$

\ForEach {$m_k \in \mathcal S $}
\State $d \gets ||m_i - m_k||_2$
\If{$d \le \lambda + \epsilon$}
    \State append $m_k$ to $C$
    \If {$d > r$}
        \State $r \gets d$
    \EndIf
\EndIf
\EndFor
\State $\mathcal{L} \gets (\lambda - r)^2$
\State Update $\lambda$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document} 

Missing number, treated as zero in those 3 lines
How to fix this.
Thank you very much
Edit
Thanks to @Teepeemm comment, I remove the package \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} and it worked!

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Welcome to tex.sx.  Please make this into compilable code that produces the errors you describe.  That is, start with \documentclass and end with \end{document} (replacing those # by %).  Then nobody has to guess your environment.

Hi. I have edited. Thank you

You've completed your code, but you've added so much more than we need.  Can you remove the parts that you don't think are related to the error?  For example, all of those \includes are files we don't have, but they shouldn't be related to the problem.  And all of the language definitions (for which you should probably be using babel or polyglossia).

See this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131651/36296 You can avoid such problems by not mixing syntax from different algorithm packages.

@Teepeemm hi, I just edited again

That's better (although you still have References/references.bib and several unrelated packages).  But the problem as samcarter observed is that you're trying to use algorithm (twice) and algorithm2e.  It will be far easier to decide on one and use it than to make the two packages work with each other.

@Teepeemm heyyy, it works!!!. Thank you.
