# Show vertical line for indentation of LaTeX code listing

Tags: listings, code

Is it possible to enable a continuous vertical line on code to show indentation? I am trying to use the [following code from a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books). Originally, the [documentation](http://www.pvv.ntnu.no/~berland/latex/docs/listings.pdf) suggests using showtabs and change the kind of symbol using tabs.

To emulate the effect I wanted, I turned the `showtabs=false` to `showtabs=true`, and added a line just below it as `tabs=$\mid$`

However, you can see the side effect of using it on the image below, for example in line `7`. I attempted to press space and then only tab once on line `6`, but it doesn't quite end up the way I want, it tends to press the word further. Ideally line `6` and `7` would be close to the print command, and would be a continuous line.

Is there an easier way that the code referred on the question could be adapted to do this? I tend to see this indentation vertical line quite often on the blackboard lectures, but not in latex and I find it quite a good visual clue to not clutter the code when reading it.

[image].

Comment: Did you check [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52473/is-it-possible-to-have-connecting-loop-lines-like-algorithm2e-in-algorithmic)?

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this package or post! :-) Since this one is a different package, I will wait and see if anyone has a particular solution for this current template. But I will use this one you suggested meanwhile. Edit: The only side-effect is that the current version I have loads the code directly, while this one requires to hand-edit it one by one so it is less reusable.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.