# How can I align indent of `then` in algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

When a statement of if is long, its `then` part is printed misaligned as following example:

```bash
while
    if statement
then
        undertand_this
```

Origin of code comes from following [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239198/127048). I have following code:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{tabularx, longtable}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\newcommand{\quot}{\textup{\textquotesingle}}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicor}{$ $ \mathrm{or} $ $}
\algnewcommand{\FALSE}{\textit{false}}
\algnewcommand{\TRUE}{\textit{true}}
\algnewcommand{\NOT}{\textbf{not }}
\algnewcommand{\OR}{\vee}
\algnewcommand{\AND}{\wedge}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{The Function}
    \hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \textbf{Input:} {}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \While{$TRUE$}
        \If{\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace*{}}l@{}}
                    $alper \AND understand\_some\_more \AND understand$
                \end{tabular}}
            \State{}$X = 1$
        \EndIf{}
        \EndWhile{}~\label{lwhileend:algo-storage}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to fix indent of the `then`, wanted output would be, where `then` is written inside the if statement:

```
1: while TRUE do 
2:     if alper ∧ understand_some_more ∧ underst and
           then
3:         X = 1
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you're loading three different packages (tabularx, algorithm, algpseudocode) more than once. You should only load them once each.

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200186/how-to-wrap-lines-correctly-inside-algorithmic) and maybe [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384017/how-to-wrap-lines-correctly-inside-algorithmic-more-indentation-for-children-l) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78776/forced-indentation-in-algorithmicx/86351#86351).

Comment: I have removed multiple loaded packages

Comment: I know that this doesn't solve your problem because you are using LaTeX (I see it from your example file). Yet let me note that if you use OpTeX and not LaTeX, then there is no problem. OpTeX users have trick 0078 for pseudo-codes, see  http://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#algol and they have direct control of indentation: the indentation in the source is equal to indentation of the output. Moreover, the source looks more transparent, see example at the URL of the trick. And your example has following source: http://petr.olsak.net/img/algoli.png

Comment: Hmm the referred answer uses `algorithm2e` package, while you use `algpseudocode`. Hence it seems the `tabular` trick doesn't work for you, and can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```tex
%\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}            % for float env `algorithm`
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} % for env `algorithmic`

\algnewcommand{\AND}{\wedge}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{The Function}
    \textbf{Input:}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \While{$TRUE$}
          \If{$alper \AND understand\_some\_more \AND understand$}
            \State $X = 1$
          \EndIf
        \EndWhile~\label{lwhileend:algo-storage}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note in OP's screenshot, "then" starts a new line because the "if ... then" is longer than the line width, hence wrapped into two lines.

**Update**

A new command `\algoIndent{<num of level>}` is provided:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm}            % for float env `algorithm`
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} % for env `algorithmic`

\algnewcommand{\AND}{\wedge}

\newcommand\algoIndent[1]{%
  \linebreak\hspace*{\dimexpr\algorithmicindent*#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{The Function}
    \textbf{Input:}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \While{$TRUE$}
          \If{$alper \AND understand\_some\_more \AND understand$\algoIndent{2}}
            \State $X = 1$
          \EndIf
        \EndWhile~\label{lwhileend:algo-storage}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In double column "then" starts a new line because the "if ... then" is longer than the line width like you said, I was specifically asking question for that case. In the wrapped lines, can we have indent before `then`?

Comment: @alper Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the update